# problem integrating ObjC pod into a Swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, lottie

## the setup

I have an iOS App `MY-App` which uses my own framework `MY-Framework`. Both are written in `swift`. The app only handles user authentification and passes an access token to `MY-Framework`. `MY-Framework` then handles the entire ScreenFlow and business logic. The goal is to distribute the `MY-Framework` to customers to use it in their apps.

a minimal sample of the project setup exhibiting this problem is available here: https://github.com/vprimachenko/lottie-pod-problem-sample

now I was to enhance my framework provided views with some animations and were to use [lottie](/questions/tagged/lottie) for it. i am using [cocoapods](/questions/tagged/cocoapods) version`1.6.0-pre`

### Naïve attempt

i created a `Podfile` with following content

```rb
target 'fw' do
  pod 'lottie-ios'
end
```

which resulted in a compile error in the framework

```
./fw/fw/File.swift:4:8: error: no such module 'Lottie'
import Lottie
       ^
```

### frameworks

after some googling i changed my `Podfile` to:

```rb
target 'fw' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'lottie-ios'
end
```

result: Runtime crash

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Lottie.framework/Lottie
  Referenced from: .../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fw.framework/fw
  Reason: image not found
```

### modular headers maybe?

[cocoapods](/questions/tagged/cocoapods) release notes mention `use_modular_headers!`, lets try that:

```rb
target 'fw' do
 use_modular_headers!
 pod 'lottie-ios'
end
```

result: compiler error in the containing app

```
./app/app/ViewController.swift:3:8: error: missing required module 'Lottie'
import fw
      ^
```

### maybe both?

```rb
target 'fw' do
 use_modular_headers!
 use_frameworks!
 pod 'lottie-ios'
end
```

result: runtime crash

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Lottie.framework/Lottie
 Referenced from: .../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fw.framework/fw
 Reason: image not found
```

### the hack

after some trying around I was able to solve the situation by providing my own bringing header for `Lottie` but this feels more like a duct-tape rather than a proper solution. I will still post this later as an additional answer.

## My Question

how do i use properly integrate `lottie-ios` cocoapod in such a way that it is completely contained in `MY-Framework`, so when i share it to a customer they can just drop it into their App and not worry about any dependencies?

Releasing it as a private pod with dependencies is sadly not an option.

Comment: Is this a possibility if you can make your MY-Framework a private pod. In that way Cocoapods will manage everything and it should work correctly (actually I tried install lottie in my framework and it worked for me using cocoapods)

Comment: Valerij, have you tried adding the Lottie framework to the "Embed Frameworks" step in the Build Phases? And one more thing - what Cocoapods version are you using right now?

Comment: @qtngo thought about that but its not an option in my current distribution scheme
@edopelawi tried both with `1.5.0` and `1.6.0-pre` tried that, the app did still crash

Comment: What happen when you do "pod 'lottie-ios'" in your framwork's podfile? You said you have linker error problem, what's that error?

Comment: @qtngo plain "framework not found" thing, went away after updating cocoapods to `1.6.0`. i actually reproduced the setup in a tiny project, prob will rephrase the question and link that example, gimme a few hours :)

Comment: have you pod install? open the project from xcworkspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to use `objective-c` code in `swift` is using bridging headers, take a look at this:

[Importing Objective-C into Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift)

you need to create a bridging header and add it to your project then inside the .h file you created simply add :

`#import <Lottie/Lottie.h>`

Answer (score 1):

> how do i use properly integrate lottie-ios cocoapod in such a way that
>   it is completely contained in MY-Framework, so when i share it to a
>   customer they can just drop it into their App and not worry about any
>   dependencies?

I don't think you want to do this. What if your customer's app already uses the Lottie framework, possibly a different version than used in MY-Framework?

A typical way to solve this is to require your client to use Lottie as a dependency. If you're using cocoapod, your clients won't really notice, and it is common practice. You specify your dependency using spec.dependency at https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html)

If really desperate, you could copy all the source of Lottie into MY-framework, and make sure they are defined in their own module to avoid clashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually copy Lottie-ios Framework to your private CocoaPod framework (which is My-Framework)

Comment: a manual step does not seem right, as i think there is something wrong with the `lottie-ios` Pod itself, or i missed some setting when adding it to my `Podfile`